# Given $f$ integrable and $\int_E f\geq 0$ for every $E$ measurable set prove $f(x)\geq 0$ almost everywhere.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, measurable-functions

Prove that if $f$ is integrable on $\mathbb{R}^d$ and $\int_E f\geq 0$ for every $E$ measurable set prove $f(x)\geq 0$ almost everywhere.

Defining $F=\{x:f(x)<0\}$ I have managed to show that $\int_Ff=0$. However, there is a line a proof I am reading that follows on from $\int_Ff=0$ saying "Since $f<0 \text{ for all }  x \in F$, we conclude that $m(F)=0$" and that doesn't really make sense to me.

**Question:** I know that $\int_Ff=0$ implies $f=0$ almost everywhere in $F$. But how does one get from that to $m(F)=0$?

Proof I am reading:

[image: Proof I am reading]

Comment: Everything should be clear if you try writing down the exact meaning for $f=0$ almost everywhere in $F$.

Comment: @Bach $m(\{f\neq0\})=0$ Is this the correct meaning of $f=0$ almost everywhere in $F$? I know its wrong because I havent incorporated $F$... I've read that it means a subset of $F$ has zero measure but how would that prove that $m(F)=0$?

Comment: Are you aware of what is your $F$?

Comment: My $F$ is defined as follows $F=\{x:f(x)<0\}$?

Comment: Yes, then try combining these two facts to see...

Comment: Still not transparent to me when it comes to combining the measure zero subset of $F$ and the way $F$ is defined, but thanks for your input @Bach !

Answer (score 2):

You know that $\int_Ffdx=0$ and that $f(x)<0$ for all $x\in F$. This also means that $f(x)\neq0$ for all $x\in F$. The fact that the integral over $F$ vanishes tells two things: $f$ is zero a.e. or...